# UITableView tableHeaderView user interaction not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, xcode5, nstableheaderview

I'm using a table view with a very large header view (not section header) in order to take advantage of the various advantages of table views (performance on long lists, pull to refresh, etc).

The header is ~700 points tall and contains various interactive items - a map, two buttons & a horizontal collection view.

Currently, none of the touch events are being passed through to the controls. I have tried building my own UITableView subclass, overriding the touch events & sending them to the next responder, but this doesn't help.

Strangely, the table still scrolls fine, so I'm not sure why that's happening. I have confirmed that the events are firing through debugging.

As extra details - I'm using iOS 7, Xcode 5, autolayout is on & I'm using a lot of constraints. None of them are listed as conflicting though.

Any idea how I should resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: once check frames of those views(superviews).

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean. Could you elaborate somewhat?

Comment: need to check weather the frames of superviews of those buttons are proper or not?

Comment: Well, the buttons render correctly & their superviews are the header itself - which is rendering with the correct frame, so I think they're fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I managed to get this working & to be honest it's difficult to tell exactly what it was I did which fixed the issue.

Basically, I had wrapped all my controls inside a main view in order to be able to apply a total height constraint to it. That view **did** have user interaction enabled, but it seems like it wasn't passing the events through for some reason.

In any case, I removed that wrapping view & everything is now working.

*shrug*

Answer (score 1):

I actually embedded all my header.xib controls into a View. After that, I was able to click on the buttons.